# JQuery hide function works for th but not td

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using the following code:
This is html table:

```
    <table id="preTbl">
       <tr>
         <th>Type</th>
         <th>Origin</th>
         <th>Count</th>
         <th>Age Range</th>
         <th>Gender</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in returnData" class="centered">
           <td>{{ row.TypeName }}</td>
           <td>{{ row.Origin }}</td>
           <td>{{ row.Count }}</td>
           <td>{{ row.ageRange}}</td>
           <td>{{ row.gender}}</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
```

My JS function with user clicks search:

```
$("#preTbl th:nth-child(4)").hide();
$("#preTbl td:nth-child(4)").hide();
```

The th hides fine, but the td will not hide.

Comment: Please add more relevant code.

Comment: Is the td a child of an element that isn't hidden? Or is it the direct child of th?

Comment: Please show the html

Comment: Works fine, when I test it: https://jsfiddle.net/tbpwa2uL/

Comment: You failed to mention that you were using angular. Why are you using jQuery for this and where are you running that code? My guess is you are calling it before angular has even compiled the view. Provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/367/)**.

> The **:nth-child(n)** pseudo-class is easily confused with **:eq(n)**, even though the two can result in dramatically different matched elements. With **:nth-child(n)**, all children are counted, regardless of what they are, and the specified element is selected only if it matches the selector attached to the pseudo-class. With **:eq(n)** only the selector attached to the pseudo-class is counted, not limited to children of any other element, and the (n+1)th one (n is 0-based) is selected.

You may need to use `:eq()` or `.eq()` instead :

```
$("#preTbl th:eq(2), #preTbl td:eq(2)").hide();
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$("#preTbl th:eq(2), #preTbl td:eq(2)").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table style="width:100%" id='preTbl'>
  <tr>
    <th>Column 0</th>
    <th>Column 1</th> 
    <th>Column 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Column 0 content</td>
    <td>Column 1 content</td> 
    <td>Column 2 content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that b/c of the many styles being applied since this is a big application, I had to rely on using ng-hide. You can see read from here it has to be manually overriden because it uses !important, but it helped a lot in my case to get the job done.

[angularjs ng-hide information](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide)

Thanks and I hope this helps people in the future!